# Platforms & Settings clarification?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

In `Eclipse` we had :

- `minSdkVersion` (which controls the lowest level you say your application can run on)
- `targetSdkVersion` (which controls any automatically applied backward compatibility features - important if you haven't tested your application on the newest API as of yet)
- Project build target (which is the platform chooser)

But after moving to Android-Studio(1/1.02) there are many additional settings  , which I don't know When should I use each.

I will reference each with a number.

**Question :**

Looking at the most used platforms :

[image]

And assuming I want to target JellyBean *and* KitKat : (most of devices)

How should I config *each numbered section* from  those Android Studio Project Settings tabs:

From the `properties` tab :

[image]

And from the `Flavors` (*what is Flavor anyway?*)tab :

[image]

```
1-  ?
2-  ?
3-  ? 
4-  ?
5-  ?
6-  ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Compile SDK Version is the same as "Project Build Target" in Eclipse.
2. Build Tools Version - always use latest.
3. Source compatibility - whether you want to allow Java 7 features (or at least the limited set accepted by Android, such as the `<>` construction).
4. Same, but for the generated class files (whether they are Java 6 or Java 7 format).
5. Same as minSdkVersion in Eclipse (lowest Android version to support).
6. Same as targetSdkVersion in Eclipse (for compatibility shims).

As for flavors, they are basically build variants (for example, you can include different implementations of the same class for debug/release, trial/full, &c).

Comment: In 1 : can I choose the latest ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir The same you would've picked in Eclipse. Generally, yes.

Comment: So I guess I was wrong also with eclipse. So let me please ask : if I choose the latest ( in #1) - so people with 4.1.x ( for example) won't be able to run my app ....right ? ( because I compiled it to API 21....am I right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, they will be able to run the app as long as their device is >= `minSdkVersion`. Setting a higher compileSDK will allow you to use "newer" features, but you should be careful do this conditionally.

Comment: Thanks for reply , but if I write code , how would I know that this `xxx()` function  ( among other hundreds) should be conditionally checked ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir The compiler will warn you (as Lint did in Eclipse) when you're using methods that are not available on `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: One last thing : isn't it dangerous to use 1.7 ? my course teacher  told me that most devices run java 1.6  , so if I write java code  , it may not run on their device ... can you please clarify this point ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Support for some features of Java 1.7 was added some time ago. Let me see if I can find the link...

Comment: @RoyiNamir Here (https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) SDK Tools 22.6: "Added support for Java 7 language features like multi-catch, try-with-resources, and the diamond operator. These features require version 19 or higher of the Build Tools. Try-with-resources requires minSdkVersion 19; the rest of the new language features require minSdkVersion 8 or higher"